# jQuery AJAX API interaction. How to use a html view to handle data output?

Tags: php, html, ajax, templates, view

At the moment, I have an interaction that goes like this:

> AJAX call to my site controller -> API content loaded through PHP and
>   output -> javascript outputting view directly into page

Is there a way to load in HTML from some sort of external file?

I don't want to end up doing something like this, as it makes changing the html messy.

```
html = '';

for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    html += '<div class="blah"><b>Content goes here<b><br>';
        html += '<div class="blah_nested">' + jsonData[i].awesomeness + '</div>';
    html += '</div>';

    $("#some_div").html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a php file which contains that code and takes the json response in the request.

example (data.php):

```
 <div class="blah"><b>Content goes here<b><br>
    <div class="blah_nested"><?php echo $_GET['jsondata']; ?></div>
 </div>
```

then do:

```
html = "";
for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
     $.get('data.php?jsondata=' + jsonData[i].awesomeness, function(response){
        html += response;
     });
}
```

**I edited to make it match his original code more directly.**

Comment: This was the perfect reply for me, until I tried accessing the view. The problem is that I am using framework specific methods in the view, and since I'm loading only the view, they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make an html file containing all your repeatable code.

For example in your html file called templates you may have:

```
<div class="blah"><b>Content goes here<b><br>
    <div class="blah_nested"></div>
</div>
```

Then in your js you can use .get to grab that code.

```
       $.get('templates.html', function(html){
            var h = $(html);
            var blah = h.find('.blah').html();
       });
```

Now you've got your code. You'll still have to put it in a for loop, and you'll still have to put in your information which would look something like this:

`$('blah_nested').text(jsonData[i].awesomeness);`

But now you don't have to go to your js to make changes to html. It's a little bit more js code, but it keeps everything separate.